# List sort by number or alphabetical if number is the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I am trying to get my final list to be sorted based on the score for each film at the end (descending order) but two of my movies return the same score and I would like to sort the movies in this case by alphabetical order if the score at the end is the same. How could I go about trying to do this? I have used sorted() to sort by the numbers but I am not sure how to go about trying to get it to sort by number first and then sort by alphabetical order if the scores are the same

```
import datetime, json

def convert_to_json(data):
    return json.loads(data)

def get_movie_score(movie, preferences):

    ratings = {
        "dislike": -20,
        "indifferent": 0,
        "like": 10,
        "adore": 30,
        "love": 50
        }
    brand_score = ratings.get(preferences["brand"].get(movie["brand"])) or 0
    type_score = ratings.get(preferences["contentType"].get(movie["contentType"])) or 0

    return movie["popularityScore"] + brand_score + type_score


def main():

    content_data = """[{ "title": "The Incredibles", "brand": "Pixar",
"popularityScore": 98, "contentType": "movie" },

{ "title": "Cars", "brand": "Pixar","popularityScore": 98,
"contentType": "movie" },

{ "title": "Avatar", "brand": "21st Century Fox",
"popularityScore":  99, "contentType": "movie" }]"""


    brand_preferences = '{"Star Wars": "love", "Disney": "like", "Marvel": "dislike", "Pixar": "dislike"}'
    content_type_preferences = '{"movie": "like", "series": "like", "short": "dislike"}'
    movies = json.loads(content_data)
    preferences = {
        "brand": json.loads(brand_preferences),
        "contentType": json.loads(content_type_preferences)
        }

    complete = {}
    showAll = []s
    for movie in movies:
        score = get_movie_score(movie, preferences)
        complete[movie["title"]] = score

    # Sorting the items
    showAll = list(complete.items())

    print(sorted(showAll, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True))

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
[('Avatar', 109), ('The Incredibles', 88), ('Cars', 88)]
```

Desired output: (if numbers are the same, sort by alphabetical order for those instead)

```
[('Avatar', 109), ('Cars', 88)], ('The Incredibles', 88)
```

Comment: `print(sorted(showAll, key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0]), reverse=True))`?

Comment: Nope, `print(sorted(showAll, key=lambda tup: (-tup[1], tup[0])))` because you want a descending order for ratings, but an ascending order for names.

Comment: Seems there is an exact dupe for what you want to do ... I found it via google: `python list sort by number desc then alphabetically site:stackoverflow.com` - 1st hit.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @Lenormju, I implemented your solution, thanks!